# Coordinates within viewing frustum

Tags: opengl

Is there a way of defining or getting what coordinates are visible within the viewing frustum created by the gluPerspective method? My quad will not display.
This is the initialisation code :

```
GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
GL11.glLoadIdentity();
GLU.gluPerspective(45, width/height, 1, 100);
GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
GL11.glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600);
GL11.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
```

This is the rendering code :

```
GL11.glLoadIdentity();
GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
GL11.glColor3f(0, 0, 0);

GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);

GL11.glVertex3f(1, 1, 5);
GL11.glVertex3f(10, 1, 5);
GL11.glVertex3f(10, 10, 5);
GL11.glVertex3f(1, 10, 5);

GL11.glEnd();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is the initialisation code:

This is not initialization code, this state setting. It belongs to the rendering code. It is idiomatic (though not necessary) to put glViewport, glClearColor and glClearDepth before setting the projection matrix.

Your quad is probably not showing up, because it's outside the viewing limits. At the near plane the limits of gluPerspective are

```
aspect = width/height
fov_ = atan2(fov)
right = near * aspect * fov_
left = -right
top = near * fov_
bottom = -top
```